# Predict the product of reaction of quinone and hydrochloric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

**This is the question:**

[image: Question]

**And this is my solution:**

[image: Solution]

In the last step, I have tautomerised, and in the second last step, **there is no double bond between carbon attached with Cl** and OH (just some cutout work)

The answer given is B, but my answer comes out to be C.

Comment: You've already been told about improper formatting...

Comment: Arrows flow from negative to positive charges in general. In other words, nucleophiles attack electrophiles. The arrow going from the H+ is incorrect, all arrows involving H+ should point toward H+, as it can only be an electrophile.

Comment: @Mithoron, I really don't remember. :(

Comment: Doesn't it look better now?

Comment: @Mithoron, yes it is. Probably while putting it in bold, I though that whole of it was important. Still thanks!

Comment: I think your answer is correct, although I haven't seen this exact reaction reported in SciFinder. If this is from an instructor, ask how B can be produced.

Comment: @Dissenter Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

The product of the addition of one chloride ion (C) is easily oxidized by atmospheric oxygen (radical mechanism). The obtained 2-chloro-1,4-benzoquinone is susceptible to conjugate addition of another chloride ion, this happens chemoselectively at the more electron deficient double bond which has already a chlorine attached to one carbon atom.
[image]

Comment: Which leads to the next question: Why is 2,3-dichlorohydroquinone not readily oxidised by atmospheric oxygen?

Comment: @Jan because it is already oxidized. Chlorine is a moderately electron-withdrawing group, and two chlorine atoms make ring electron-deficient enough to not being readily oxidized. Moving further this road, I point out that DDQ (dichloro-dicianot-quinone) is a rather strong oxidizer by organic chemistry standards.

Comment: @permeakra Thanks, I suspected something like that but confirmation is always nice.

Comment: Well, aren't electron deficient rings more likely to be oxidised?

Comment: No, because the first step of the radical mechanism would be a single electron transfer from the aromatic ring to oxygen, producing a radical-cation. Cations are destabilized by electron-withdrawing groups.

Comment: @Marko Can you give a link to the radical mechanism you are talking about?